# Yii select column from different table with cacvtive data provider

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 table Customer and Customer Plan

Customer table
Id  Name
1   John
2   Deol
3   test3
4   test4

Customer Plan table 
id   cust_id  status 
1      2         0
2      3         1
3      4         1

I want to get all customer ID and there Plan id (if exist)
get all the data by doing

```
 $criteria->join ='where t.id NOT IN (select cust_id from customer_plan) or t.id in (select customer_id from customer_plan  where foblu_customer_plan.babytel_status = 0)';
```

By this i get ID of customer table but i want to get both table  unique ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a relation in between Customer & CustomerPlan.
You can create a relation in model relations function.

```
Public function relations()
{
   return array(
      'customerPlan' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CustomerPlan', 'cust_id'),
   );
}
```

Now use this relation to find out related records:

```
$criteria->with = array('customerPlan');
```

Get the relational records of Customer model:

```
$customer->customerPlan
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have done this  
$criteria->condition = "`customerPlan`.service_id = 0";


but still get an error

Comment: The error is 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customerPlan.service_id' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`,`t`.`status` AS `t0_c21`, `t`.`active_status` AS `t0_c22` FROM `foblu_customer_master` `t` WHERE (`customerPlan`.service_id = 0) LIMIT 10 
And my code in Customer master model in search function is as :
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('customerPlan');
$criteria->condition = "`customerPlan`.service_id = 0";
and service_id is exist in my customer plan table.

Comment: have you defined relations correctly because in your query their is no join operation between these two tables so please do it correctly.

Comment: I set the relation is as below 

public function relations()
 {
  return array(
   'customerPlan' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CustomerPlan', 'customer_id'),
  );
 }
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `foblu_customer_master` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `foblu_customer_plan` `customerPlan` ON (`customerPlan`.`customer_id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE ( , `customerPlan`.service_id = 0)
it shows outer join in it when i put "," in condition (in where clause. forced error to display sql) but when i remove this "," then it shows error that column is not found and no outer join in this sql